# C++ Assignment operator for class that contains a unique pointer member variable

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, assignment-operator

I understand that if I have a class with a smart unique pointer, it is not possible to assign that class to another instance, as a unique pointer cannot be copied. I understand that I could make the unique pointer a shared pointer and this would solve the problem. But what if I did not want to share ownership of the pointer? Is it possible to create an assignment operator that moves the unique pointer and copies the other variables?

I have read that you can use `std::move` to pass ownership.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 

struct GraphStructure { };

class test {

        int a;
        std::vector<int> vector;
        std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure> Graph_; 
 };

 int main () {

     test t1;
     auto t2 = t1;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't moving make `t1` useless? What exact problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Moving wouldn't make sense in given example, but in conjunction with a `std::vector`; we'd need moving then for re-allocations.

Comment: You can create a move assignment operator which moves everything (in this case, with `test& operator=(test&& other) = default;`), but that would also move the vector instead of copying it. If you implemented it manually you could do what you ask (are you getting stuck trying it), but it wouldn't behave as most people using your class would expect, so I would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Also, in `main`, you never use an assignment operator. The second line calls the copy constructor (which is implicitly deleted because of the `unique_ptr`), not the copy assignment operator, even though it uses the `=` syntax.

Comment: You probably want to copy the `GraphStructure` that the other object's `Graph_` owns, not steal it. That's the "normal" behaviour of assignment (and initialisation, which is what you're doing), and what you would do if you used raw pointers.

Answer (score 6):

The default *copy* constructor of class `test` is deleted because of a member (`graph_`) not being copiable (if you still could copy in any meaningful way, e. g. by creating a *deep* copy of the graph member, you'd have to implement on your own copy constructor). In contrast, the default *move* constructor still exists (`std::unique_ptr` is movable). So what you *can* do is the following:

```
test t1;
auto t2 = std::move(t1);
```

Be aware, though, that `t1` then *won't* hold any object any more (you *moved* the object, so you moved its contents to another one) and the object previously held by `t2` is destroyed. If this is a meaningful state is up to you to decide...

Side note: What I wrote about copy and move constructors applies for copy and move assignment as well...

Answer (score 3):

#### Fixing this the easy way

If `GraphStructure` is a class or struct without any virtual member functions, this is easy to do. We can write a function to duplicate the data inside a `unique_ptr` to create a new `GraphStructure`:

```
std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure> duplicate(std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure> const& ptr)
{
    return std::make_unique<GraphStructure>(*ptr);
}
```

Once we have `duplicate`, we can use this class to write a copy constructor for test:

```
class test {
    std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure> ptr;
    std::vector<int> values;
   public:
    // this can be defaulted
    test() = default;
    // we use duplicate to create a copy constructor
    test(const test& source) 
      : ptr(duplicate(source.ptr)))
      , values(source.values)
    {}
    // we can use the default move constructor
    test(test&&) = default;

    test& operator=(test const& source) {
        ptr = duplicate(source.ptr);
        values = source.values; 
        return *this;
    }
    // we can use the default move assignment operator 
    test& operator=(test&&) = default;
};
```

#### What if GraphStructure has virtual methods?

In this case, add a virtual `clone` method to GraphStructure that returns a new `std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure>`:

```
class GraphStructure {
   public:
    // override this method in child classes
    virtual std::unique_ptr<GraphStructure> clone() {
        return std::make_unique<GraphStructure>(*this);
    }
    virtual ~GraphStructure() {}
};
```

Then, use `.clone()` in place of `duplicate`

Comment: You should usually prefer `make_unique` over `unique_ptr<T>(new ...)`, because if something goes wrong in the expression then there is no corresponding `delete` to your `new` and you have a memory leak. See https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/ (except that `make_unique` is now a standard function instead of something you need to write).

Comment: If `new` completes successfully then there is no way for something to go wrong in the function because the constructor for std::unique_ptr is guaranteed noexcept by the standard

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez That's true in this case because of the simplicity of the expression. However if you use the raw pointer constructor in an expression with other unsequenced operations, something might throw between `new` and the `unique_ptr` constructor and leak the memory. The line in your code isn't wrong, it's just not reinforcing good habits, which is a concern when offering help to someone learning about smart pointers.

Comment: *"If GraphStructure is a class or struct without any virtual member functions"*. Else it should provide some `Clone` method.

Comment: Thank you - I updated it to show a clone() method and to use make_unique